# Does the Hover action provoke?

Tags: actions, opportunity-attack, pathfinder-2e

The [Hover](http://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=94) action has a Move trait so am I right in assuming this would provoke an [attack of opportunity](http://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=145)?

Comment: Related to my other question about ghost's flying: [Do ghosts have to hover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176118/do-ghosts-have-to-hover)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct.

Attack of Opportunity can be triggered by a "move action". The section titled "Move Actions That Trigger Reactions" (Core Rules, pg. 474) clarifies that this means an action with the move trait.

Fly has the move trait. So if you use the Fly action for any usage, including to hover, then you have used an action with the move trait, and may trigger Attack of Opportunity.